# SELECT inside in INSERT INTO in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have this insert with a SELECT but it gives me error and it says missing a right parenthesis but I don't know where

```
INSERT INTO DETALLEVENTA(Idventa, IdProducto, Cantidad, Precio_Uni, Descuento)
VALUES((SELECT IdVenta 
        FROM Venta WHERE ROWNUM = 1 
        ORDER BY IdVenta DESC), pIdProducto, pCantidad, pPrecio_Uni, pDescuento);
```

Comment: I'm going to assume it is that subquery. Swap that out for something simple, like a blank string or a number, and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming from the `ORDER BY IdVenta DESC`, which isn't expected at that point in the statement. If you use a subquery in the values clause then it has to return a single value, and ordering a single value doesn't make much sense. (It's a more general rule than that, though in some places it's allowed but ignored).

Since you seem to have the ordering for the `ROWNUM`, you need another level of subquery anyway:

```
INSERT INTO DETALLEVENTA(Idventa, IdProducto, Cantidad, Precio_Uni, Descuento)
VALUES((
  SELECT IdVenta 
  FROM (
    SELECT IdVenta 
    FROM Venta
    ORDER BY IdVenta DESC
  )
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1
  ), pIdProducto, pCantidad, pPrecio_Uni, pDescuento);
```

Ignoring that it's in a values clause for now, if you just did:

```
SELECT IdVenta 
FROM Venta
WHERE ROWNUM = 1 
ORDER BY IdVenta DESC
```

then the `rownum` filter is applied first, and you then order that single row, which is pointless. The row you actually get is indeterminate - it depends on how the optimiser executes the query, and can vary even between calls of the same query.

What you actually want is:

```
SELECT IdVenta 
FROM (
  SELECT IdVenta 
  FROM Venta
  ORDER BY IdVenta DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

where the overall result set is ordered first, and then in the outer query the `rownum` filter is applied. Doing it like that means you will get the `IdVenta` you expect, the one that orders last.

So, you need to embed that same subquery into the values clause, as its own subquery.

There are probably better ways of doing this; you seem to be running this inside a PL/SQL block so you coudl do that query once and store in a variable, for instance. From 12c there are other ways to get the 'top' row as well. Or you can skip the subquery, and the values clause, by changing to an `insert .. select` as @Barbaros showed.

Answer (score 2):

You may use like this :

```
INSERT INTO DETALLEVENTA(Idventa, IdProducto, Cantidad, Precio_Uni, Descuento)
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
   SELECT IdVenta,pIdProducto, pCantidad, pPrecio_Uni, pDescuento 
     FROM Venta 
    ORDER BY IdVenta DESC
   )
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alias the subquery that should resolve the issue

Comment: You can't alias a subquery within the `values()` clause. If the other errors were fixed, adding an alias would then throw "ORA-00917: missing comma`.